# C : How to stop the loop when getting the end of input from keyboard or file while using scanf one char at a time

Tags: c, scanf

```
void main(void)
{
    char character;

    do {
        scanf("%c", &character);
        printf("%c", character);
    } while (character != EOF);
}
```

I'm going to process the input character by character, and I am only allowed to use scanf(). However, the while loop does not stop. Since I may need to process the input with multiple-line strings, it is impossible to add one more condition: character != '\n'.
Can somebody help me with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should also look at this question [scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-new-line-char-in-buffer) which as the answers say can be solved by placing a space before `%c`, to filter out leading whitespace. For example `scanf(" %c", &character);` Some other format specifiers like `%d` and `%f` and `%s` do that automatically, but `%c` does not.

Comment: Curious, does the loop stop if you type in `ÿ`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start it should be `int main...`

Also you need to check the return value from `scanf` - please read the manual page.

Taking this into account, the code should look like this

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char character;

    while (scanf("%c", &character) == 1) {
       if (character != '\n) {
         printf("%c", character)
       }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an incorrect expectation.  When `scanf()` encounters the end of the input before either matching an input item or recognizing a matching failure, it *returns* `EOF`.  Under no circumstance does it modify the value of the datum associated with an input item that has not been matched.

You are ignoring `scanf`'s return value, which is generally a perilous thing to do, and instead testing whether `scanf` records `EOF` in the object associated with the input item, which, in your particular case, it must not *ever* do.